# Insert data from CSV file into a hibernate table using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, csv

I am loading a CSV file into a mysql table. However, after inserting the CSV file into the table using the below code only the first CSV column is getting inserted.

```
session.createSQLQuery("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE :filename INTO TABLE ledger_main_account
(ID,MAIN_LEDGER,MAIN_LEDGER_AMOUNT_BAL,MAIN_LEDGER_DESC,MAIN_LEDGER_GST,MAIN_LEDGER_ID)")
.setString("filename", headerName).executeUpdate();
```

**CSV File:**

[image: CSV_DATA_FILE]

**Table after inserting:**

[image: Table after inserting:]

**Why is the insert not updating the table to match the CSV file? Is the CSV incorrect or the code to insert it?**

Comment: you mean Hey I have a spreadsheet picture

Comment: so what are the field types in this table? also note that a csv null is just some text containing the letters `n`, `u`, `l`. sql nulls can NOT be represented in csv.

Comment: Clarified question to help make it easier to understand and read

Comment: Try changing your MySQL to account for "," and column headers.  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filename INTO TABLE ledger_main_account
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;

Comment: Parameter filename does not exist as a named parameter in [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filename INTO TABLE ledger_main_account FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY] i got this error `session.createSQLQuery(
      "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filename INTO TABLE ledger_main_account FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY")
      .setString("filename", headerName).executeUpdate();`